# Excel - find values in a column except for value in current row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a workbook as follows ...

```
     Col# -> 1     2           3       

 Row #
   1         5     London      
   2         6     Paris   
   3         4     New York  
   4         2     Joburg  
   5         1     Oslo  
   6         5     Rio
```

What I want to do is, for each cell in column 3, return a column 2 entry ONLY when another column 1 value matches the value of the current row (otherwise return nothing). 
For example, in Row 1, Col 3, I want see 'Rio' i.e. match row 1, col 1 with another same value in column 1 as the row 1 (i.e. '5') and return column 2 value (Rio).
And in row Row 6, Col 3, I want see 'London' by matching row 1, col 6 with with another same value of column 1 of the the Rio row (i.e. '5') and return column 2 value London.

I'm been wrestling with this and I think it needs some kind of match/find formula to match values in column 1 EXCEPT for the current row. i.e. when evaluating row 1 col 3, I only want to find the '5' in row 6, col 1, and then return Rio, not find the '5' of the current row where the formula is being calculated. 
VLOOKUP and INDEX/MATCH will either find the first value or all of the values, (neither of which I want)

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the values in new column i.e. column 4, right?

Comment: If there are multiple other rows besides the one you are on, do want to pull back all of them?

Comment: Manish, Yes, add values in to a new column, 4.

Comment: Alan, in my use case there should never be more than two numbers the same in column #1, so only need to find the other value that is the same

Answer (score 0):

This code is sample for just six rows:

```
Sub TEST()

For i = 1 To 6
For j = 1 To 6

If i <> j Then

If ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 1).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value Then
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 2).Value

End If
End If
Next j
Next i



End Sub
```

Try and let know if you need any more help.

Answer (score 0):

As your data in column A will never have more than two instances of one value, here is the formula that I come up with:

```
=IF(
COUNTIF($C$1:$C1,LOOKUP(2,1/($A$1:$B$10=$A2),$B$1:$B$10))<1,
LOOKUP(2,1/($A$1:$B$10=$A2),$B$1:$B$10),
INDEX($A$1:$B$10,MATCH($A2,$A$1:$A$10,0),2)
)
```

Place this formula in cell C2 and drag it down and you will get your result, like this:

[image]

Let me know if you find any issue.